# Level curves of Gaussian Integral from $x$ to $y$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble understanding how to approach this one.

$$ g(x,y) = \int_x^y e^{-t^2} dt $$

Sketch the level curves of $g$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The level curves are perpendicular to the gradient of the function.
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y)
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\int_x^ye^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\left(-e^{-x^2},e^{-y^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the direction of a level curve at any point $(x,y)$ would be
$$
\left(e^{-y^2},e^{-x^2}\right)
$$
which is parallel to
$$
\left(e^{x^2},e^{y^2}\right)
$$